# Cross Platform Remote Command Execution Utility

Tags: linux, windows

Is there any reliable tool/binary available for executing remote commands?

e.g. A binary/script/tool running on Linux machine can send a request to any remote machine (Windows or Unix) to execute command and capture its output, return code...

PsExec is only  "windows to windows" which doesn't help across the platforms...

Comment: `openssh` server, with it's own client on unix and putty on windows.

Comment: I would prefer writing my own socket server-client script..

Comment: What about encryption, authentication? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: And btw: Why are you asking then? Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: Not a misunderstanding... I just want to automate few admin operations in a large data center and its not possible for me to keep eye on SSH failures all the time...